# Error in sending data with this.props.Navigation.navigate react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am sending user id in navigation but i am not able to get id on the detail page here is my code...

```
<FlatList
          style={{ paddingLeft: 5 }}
          data={this.state.TopRatedData}
          ListEmptyComponent={this._listEmptyComponent}
          keyExtractor={(x, i) => i.toString()}
          renderItem={({ item }) =>
            <TouchableOpacity
              activeOpacity={0.9}
              onPress = { () => this.props.navigation.navigate("DetailDoctorscreen", {doc_id: item.ID})
              }>
              <TopRatedCard
              profileImage={{ uri: `${item.image}` }}
              specialities={`${entities.decode(item.specialities.name)}`}
              name={`${entities.decode(item.name)}`}
              sub_heading={`${entities.decode(item.sub_heading)}`}
              total_rating={`${entities.decode(item.total_rating)}`}
              average_rating={`${entities.decode(item.average_rating)}`}
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
```

In the above code i am sending `doc_id` but i am not able to fetch it on `DetailDoctorscreen`. here is the code...

```
fetchDoctorDetail = async () => {
    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
    console.log(this.props.navigation.state.doc_id);
    const response = await fetch(
      CONSTANT.BaseUrl +
      "listing/get_doctor?profile_id=" + this.props.navigation.state.doc_id
    );
    const json = await response.json();
    Alert.alert(CONSTANT.BaseUrl +
      "listing/get_doctor?profile_id=" + this.props.navigation.state.doc_id);
    this.setState({ fetchDoctor: json });
  };
```

after using `getParams`...

```
fetchDoctorDetail = async () => {
    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
    console.log(this.props.navigation.state.doc_id);
    const response = await fetch(
      CONSTANT.BaseUrl +
      "listing/get_doctor?profile_id=" + this.props.navigation.getParam('doc_id')
    );
    const json = await response.json();
    Alert.alert(CONSTANT.BaseUrl +
      "listing/get_doctor?profile_id=" + this.props.navigation.getParam('doc_id'));
    this.setState({ fetchDoctor: json });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
this.props.navigation.getParam('doc_id');
```

edit: head here for more info: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#getparam-get-a-specific-param-value-with-a-fallback

Further clarification:

Get the param within `componentDidMount`, then pass the docId var into the `fetchDoctorDetail` funciton.

Something like:

```
async componentDidMount() {
  const docId = this.props.navigation.getParam('doc_id');
  await this.fetchDoctorDetail(docId);
}

async fetchDoctorDetail = async(docId) => {
  // do all your stuff here.
}
```

note this code is not tested

Comment: Can you update the code example using the `getParam()` call?

Comment: Try the `getParam` in `componentDidMount()`, then execute the `fetchDoctorDetail` with the `doc_id` param. Something like:
`
async componentDidMount() {
  const docId = this.props.navigation.getParam('doc_id');
  await fetchDoctorDetail(docId);
}
`

Comment: please add complete sample code i am not understanding

Comment: Apologies. It's difficult to edit the code examples in the comment. I'll update the answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201326/discussion-between-mrnickel-and-s-hashmi).

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the param variable from state object of navigation instead of params object. Try the following:

```
const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
console.log('doc id =',params.doc_id);
```